full calendar no renderiza correctamente dentro de p-tabview en primeng
Tengo una aplicación con Angular donde uso primeNg, en una vista tengo esta estructura y quiero mostrar un calendario con la libreria fullcalendar
<p-card>
  <p-tabView>

    <p-tabPanel header="Header I">
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>
        <span>Calendario</span>
       </ng-template>
       <app-calendar></app-calendar>
    </p-tabPanel>

    <p-tabPanel header="Header II">
     <ng-template pTemplate="header">
       <span>{{ titleAntecedentes }}</span>
     </ng-template>
       <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </p-tabPanel>

  </p-tabView>
</p-card>

Si no utilizo p-tabView el calendario se muestra correctamente, pero al ponerlo dentro de una pestaña se muestra asi


Para darle solución al problema que me lo generaba el <p-tabView> hice lo siguiente
En el archivo principal.component.html cree una estructura parecida a esta
    <p-card>
        <div class="card_acciones">
          <div class="button_group">
            <button
              #buttonUno
              pButton
              pRipple
              type="button"
              label="Uno"
              class="button_active"
              (click)="selectOption(0)"
            ></button>
            <button
              #buttonDos
              pButton
              pRipple
              type="button"
              label="Dos"
              (click)="selectOption(1)"
            ></button>
            <button
              #buttonTres
              pButton
              pRipple
              type="button"
              label="Tres"
              (click)="selectOption(2)"
            ></button>
            <button
              #buttonCuatro
              pButton
              pRipple
              type="button"
              label="Cuatro"
              (click)="selectOption(3)"
            ></button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div></div>
      </p-card>

      <p-card>
        
          
          @if(activeIndex==0){
            <componente-hijo-uno></componente-hijo-uno>
          }

          @if(activeIndex == 1){
            <componente-hijo-dos></componente-hijo-dos>
          }
          
          @if(activeIndex ==2){
            <componente-hijo-tres></componente-hijo-tres>
          }
          

          @if(activeIndex ==3){
             <app-calendar></app-calendar>
          }
          
      </p-card>

En uno de los activeIndex uso el componente hijo calendar
en el archivo principal.component.css use:
button.button_active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--surface-500) !important;
}

para simular que estaba activa esa pestaña como en el <p-tabView>
En el archivo principal.component.ts declaré
@ViewChild('buttonUno') buttonAntecedentes!: ElementRef
@ViewChild('buttonDos') buttonHistorial!: ElementRef
@ViewChild('buttonTres') buttonRegisterDate!: ElementRef
@ViewChild('buttonCuatro') buttonEvolucion!: ElementRef

activeIndex!: number

//hice este metodo

 selectOption(option: number) {
    this.activeIndex = option


    this.buttonUno.nativeElement.classList.remove('button_active')
    this.buttonDos.nativeElement.classList.remove('button_active')
    this.buttonTres.nativeElement.classList.remove('button_active')
    this.buttonCuatro.nativeElement.classList.remove('button_active')

    if (option === 0) {
      this.buttonUno.nativeElement.classList.add('button_active')
      return
    }
    if (option === 1) {
      this.buttonDos.nativeElement.classList.add('button_active')
      return
    }
    if (option === 2) {
      this.buttonTres.nativeElement.classList.add('button_active')
      return
    }
    if (option === 3) {
      this.buttonCuatro.nativeElement.classList.add('button_active')
      return
    }


}

Con esta lógica logré simular el comportamiento del TabView.
